# quarto CLI option to make verbose output

Tags: command-line-interface, rstudio, quarto

I have a quarto project that is erroring out when I run:

```
$ quarto render test.qmd
> ERROR: PermissionDenied: Access in denied. (os error 5)
```

I'd like to run `quarto` in verbose mode, but `-v` doesn't seem to work

```
$ quarto -v render test.qmd   #gives version number
> 1.1.189
```

And -v after render doesn't appear to do anything

```
$ quarto render -v test.qmd
> ERROR: PermissionDenied: Access in denied. (os error 5)
```

I can't find the quarto CLI options listed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we run `quarto render --help`, among the options we can see the `pandoc-args`,

```
...... a part of output is shown ........


--debug                             - Leave intermediate files in place after render.

 pandoc-args...                      - Additional pandoc command line arguments.

 --log                     <level>   - Path to log file

.....
```

Then if we run `quarto pandoc --help`,

```
.............. last part of the output is shown ........

                        --verbose
                        --quiet
                        --fail-if-warnings
                        --log=FILE
                        --bash-completion
                        --list-input-formats
                        --list-output-formats
                        --list-extensions[=FORMAT]
                        --list-highlight-languages
                        --list-highlight-styles
  -D FORMAT             --print-default-template=FORMAT
                        --print-default-data-file=FILE
                        --print-highlight-style=STYLE|FILE
  -v                    --version
  -h                    --help
```

Since the `-v` flag is not in the list of options for `quarto render`, it is considered as `pandoc-args` and for pandoc, `-v` is an alias to `--version`.Therefore, running `quarto render -v test.qmd` inside a quarto project (like book) should print the pandoc version you are using.

Instead to run quarto in verbose mode, try the following,

```
quarto render --verbose test.qmd
```